# Padding in custom button doesn't work

Tags: android, xml

I have button style:

```
   <style name="NavDrawerButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/navdrawer_item</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/navdrawer_item_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>
```

In /drawable:

```
<!--Navdrawer_item.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/navdrawer_item_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/navdrawer_item_enabled" />
</selector>

<!--navdrawer_item_enabled-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

My button:

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/category1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/NavDrawerButton"
                    android:text="@string/category1"/>
```

Problem is that padding doesn't work. There is no padding between left edge of button and text inside it. I can't understard why it is so.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or explain what you mean by "title refers to the left edge of the button"?

Comment: I mean that there is no empty 16dp space between left edge of button and text inside

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code there is no error...might be in your parent layout...

string.xml

```
 <style name="NavDrawerButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="sdfg"
    style="@style/NavDrawerButton" >
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

output

[image]